# Integrating Angular 5 in J2EE application

Tags: spring, angular5

How to integrate the Angular 5 into existing J2EE application and what will directory structure for the same .

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to create a separate Frontend **WAR module** which includes the Angular app (directory structure: does not matter).

In the Maven or Gradle build of that module, have it **build the Angular app** and then **copy the resources to the static web resources** directory, so the built Angular app gets included as static resources in the WAR.

- For **Maven**, use https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin
- For **Gradle**, use https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.moowork.node

Advantages:

- the Frontend  WAR module can be integrated into the EAR, and therefore be deployed along with the backend
- the Frontend WAR module can be built in parallel to the other modules (which significantly decreases build time on parallel builds)

Comment: Actually I am integrating angular 2 into my existing application ,So i want to use this in same application ..

Comment: That's exactly what I'm proposing: a separate UI module (WAR) that goes into the *same* JEE application (EAR).